# SQL: Group by statement showing same values?

Tags: sql, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this SQL code:

```
select count(req_id), SUBMITS from requests where result='REJECT' GROUP BY SUBMITS
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
1    16-JUN-17
1    19-JUN-17
1    16-JUN-17
1    16-JUN-17
```

whereas I want:

```
3    16-JUN-2017
1    19-JUN-2017
```

Comment: maybe you have hours, minutes and seconds in your dates? what is the type of the date column?

Comment: This should not happen. Is your SUBMITS column a type DATE  or CHAR/VARCHAR? if the latest, you might have invisible chars in it

Comment: @ThomasG it's a DATE type.

Comment: In Oracle `date` columns **include** a time part - but the Oracle tools do not show that time by default (pretty stupid default I think). Change your SQL Developer to show the time as well, and you will see why this happens. You probably want `group by trunc(submits)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have hours, minutes, seconds in your `SUBMITS` column that your tool is not showing you; this way, you believe that all that rows have the same `SUBMITS` value, but they only have the same date, but different time.

If so, you only need to limit the informations to a date, without hours, minutes and seconds:

```
select count(req_id), trunc(SUBMITS)
from requests
where result='REJECT'
GROUP BY trunc(SUBMITS)
```

For example:

```
SQL> create table requests (submits date, result VARCHAR2(10), req_id NUMBER);

Table created.

SQL> insert into requests (req_id, submits, result) values (1, sysdate, 'REJECT');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into requests (req_id, submits, result) values (2, sysdate, 'REJECT');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into requests (req_id, submits, result) values (3, sysdate, 'REJECT');

1 row created.    

SQL> select count(req_id), trunc(SUBMITS)
  2  from requests
  3  where result='REJECT' 
  4  GROUP BY trunc(SUBMITS);

COUNT(REQ_ID) TRUNC(SUB
------------- ---------
            3 21-JUN-17

SQL> select count(req_id), SUBMITS
  2  from requests
  3  where result='REJECT'
  4  GROUP BY SUBMITS;

COUNT(REQ_ID) SUBMITS
------------- ---------
            1 21-JUN-17
            1 21-JUN-17
            1 21-JUN-17
```